# MySQL --secure-file-priv is set to NULL

Tags: php, mysql

Не добавляются значения в базу данных. Полез в логи, там --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled. Как включить не знаю

Comment: *Как включить не знаю* Изменить конфигурационный файл (my.ini) и перестартовать сервис.

Comment: прописывал secure-file-priv в my.ini , тогда сервер mysql не запускается

Comment: *прописывал secure-file-priv в my.ini , тогда сервер mysql не запускается* Сообщение об ошибке нам предлагается угадать? А я почти уверен, что там описана не только суть проблемы, но и путь её решения... так что логи посмотри...